# Access denied when I try to rebuild permissions as admin

Tags: users

I recently upgraded Drupal/OpenOutreach. Now, logged in as administrator (all possible permissions checked) I get a warning on every page to rebuild permissions on the site. But whenever I click to rebuild I get an Access Denied page. Note - I am not an advanced Drupal user so please make suggestions very user friendly. Thanks